# Retaining an object created in an NSThread

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, multithreading, memory-management, thread-safety

I have the following method which is spawned by a call for a new thread (using NSThread):

```
- (void) updateFMLs {   
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:someArrayFromAnotherProcess];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneLoading:) withObject:temp waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}
```

My `doneLoading:` method looks like this:

```
- (void) doneLoading:(NSArray *)obj {
    myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:obj copyItems:NO];
}
```

The contents of `myArray` become invalid. How can I preserve the contents of `myArray` so I can use them later in my app?

P.S. `myArray` is defined in the class header file.

Comment: What do you mean by "become invalid". Are they being deallocated?

Comment: BTW, you're leaking the "temp" array.  You alloc an array (+1 retain count), but you never release it.

Comment: yes they seem to become deallocated as i progress through doneLoading...even though nothing in doneLoading,except for the line shown above, alters myArray in any way

Comment: Retagged with thread-related tags, and removed less-related iPhone tags.

Answer (score 1):

If your background thread does some work and needs to 'pass' an `NSArray` to your main thread, then all doneLoading needs to do is:

```
-(void)doneLoading:(NSArray *)obj
{
    [myArray release]; // release the previous array and its objects
    myArray = [obj retain];
    // now use myArray, refresh tables, etc.
}
```

There's (likely) no need to make another copy of the array, and that might be the underlying issue. You should also call `[temp release]` after your `performSelector` call, since arguments to that are retained already.

If the contents of `myArray` are becoming valid somehow, then they are being doubly released somewhere. `myArray` will retain any objects that are added to it. You mentioned that `myArray` itself is becoming invalid, so try rewriting your background thread and your doneLoading method with this pattern.

Finally you should use `[pool drain]` in place of `[pool release]`.

Comment: What happens if the other thread goes to use `myArray` in between your `release` message and assignment of the new array?

Comment: Presumably (based on the question) he is using `myArray` on the main thread only. It appears that his background thread sets up a new model and then needs to pass it to the main thread for processing. His question is more about memory management than thread synchronization. To solve the issue you raise, he would need to add @synchronized(self){} blocks. Plus, `updateFMLs` quits immediately after `doneLoading` is to be called.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine, apart from the memory leak in `updateFMLs`. You're probably over-releasing the objects somewhere else. I'm guessing it would be wherever `someArrayFromAnotherProcess` is made.

Comment: When I debug updateFMLs - temp is filled with the correct data. When it gets passed to doneLoading and then becomes invalid is what is messing me up....

Comment: They might be deallocated when the pool is released in updateFMLs, which will happen before doneLoading is called.

Comment: If that's the case, then you have to find where you are releasing it incorrectly, and remove the release. It doesn't appear to be in the code you posted.

Comment: Tom Dalling: But the objects in the array are retained by the array, which he is leaking (it's not autoreleased). If he fixes the leak, then that will become a problem, but it isn't the problem in the code shown.

Comment: I figure it's something like [[[MyItem new] autorelease] autorelease] that will deallocate the objects even though the leaked array has a retain on them.

Comment: But 2 autoreleases will just add it twice to the same pool, and doesn't solve anything. He would have to defer one release to the receiving thread, which breaks standard Objective-C memory management rules, but perhaps justifiably in this case. This just makes me think how much cleaner all of this would be with Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch... I can't wait for the entire developer community to get their paws on Snow Leopard! :-)

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: will actually retain the argument object until the selector is run.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the options above would be to declare myArray as an atomic property in the header

```
@property (atomic,retain) NSArray *myArray;
```

Then in updateFMLs you should be able to simply call the setter from the secondary thread.  Obviously this only works if you are willing to pay the performance penalty for an atomic property.

```
- (void) updateFMLs {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool - [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:someArrayFromAnotherProcess];
    [self setMyArray:temp];
    [temp release];
    [pool drain];
}
```